# Filter or clean CSV data while loading to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, csv, command-line, filter, bulkinsert

I am loading CSV files to PostgreSQL tables using bulk load method `COPY` command. There are some fields which have bad character in it (like "|", """, ";" and so on). So I keep getting different error while loading it. I tried with tab-delimited, comma-delimited, and other options, too, but no luck.

Is there a way I can clean CSV data before loading it to PostgreSQL using `COPY`  command or is there any `COPY` command syntax which can replace the bad characters to something default?

These are the some of the syntax I have tried:

```
COPY tblsf FROM '/filelocation/test.csv' WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER ',' NULL '?';
COPY tblsf FROM '/filelocation/test.csv' WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER '|' NULL '?';  
COPY tblsf FROM '/filelocation/test.csv' WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER E'\t' NULL '?';
COPY tblsf FROM '/filelocation/test.csv' WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER '<>' NULL '?';
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your file is mal-formed, you have basically two options: (a) prepare it before you attempt to `COPY` to PostgreSQL; (b) `COPY` the records into a single-column table, then 'clean' the data within PostgreSQL.

Comment: @Nicarus There are another two options: (c) use `copy ... from program` form of the `copy` command (since v 9.3); (d) ask file's provider to fix its format corresponding to CSV standard.

Comment: @Abelisto - It is either "cleaned" within PostgreSQL or outside of it. :-)

Comment: to get good answers, you should post some sample rows

Comment: do add the sample lines as discussed I see that your answer as already been nuked.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you get a file that is not encoded using utf-8. Try this:

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 -c /filelocation/test.csv > /filelocation/test_clean.csv
```

And then try the Postgresql copy (below command assumes that fields are separated by commas):

```
COPY tblsf FROM '/filelocation/test_clean.csv' WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER ',';
```

If you have a mal-formed file, for example:

```
company,owner
John's Pizza, LLC,John Smith
Burger Co,Jones, Mike
```

You need to resave the data in a corrected format. For example:

```
"company","owner"
"John's Pizza, LLC","John Smith"
"Burger Co","Jones, Mike"
```

Once you have a clean file, you can edit it and resave it using a different delimiter (for example in Excel, or using the csv module in Python). Before saving it with the new delimiter, you will want to scrub that delimiter out of the file, for example, in the case of pipes `|`:

```
sed -i 's/|//g' test_clean.csv
```